# Image loading animation

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm looking for a good example on how to have an image loading animation in my metro xaml app.
I have an image control that has a source set through mvvm binding directly to an URL.

So I know there is the ImageOpened and the ImageFailed events to stop any animation, but when does the 'download' start to start it?
Because the second time the app starts the image is still cached and the ImageOpened event isn't fired anymore.

Any tips/tricks?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [DownloadProgress event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.downloadprogress.aspx)?  It looks like the event args contain a Progress value between 0-100 that you could use to determine if a new download is starting.

Also, there is a generic [XAML animation library sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Animations-f758de70) in case that helps.

Comment: Yes... but my problem is more 'when' to start the animation and when to stop it in reference to the image loading. So this example is no solution.

Comment: Ha! So using the downloadprogress on the BitmapImage class, I'll take a look at that, see if that works with the Image control.

Comment: Updated with info on DownloadProgress event, but not sure if that will work with caching.  What exactly is the cue that should cause this animation to fire?  I'm guessing that it should fire the animation the first time that the image is downloaded, but do you want it to fire every time the app starts?  (From your description: "Because the second time the app starts the image is still cached...")  Maybe the event causing the animation should be the app starting or page loading etc?  (Just thinking out loud; I may be misunderstanding you again.)  :)

Comment: No good thinking :) So yes I'm actually searching for the 'begin' event and page/control loaded is not good enough, because like I stated the image can be cached and than I don't need to show an animation. I would rather think the image control has it's own prop or event, but alas. Still need to verify the downloadprogress event.

Comment: OK, if you only need to show the animation when the image changes and is downloaded, then DownloadProgress sounds like the best bet.  Let me know if it works.  :)

Comment: The ImageExtensions.FadeInOnLoaded property and ImageExtensionsTestPage in the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) seem to indicate the ImageOpened event occurs every time the BitmapImage is used in the app, not only between restarts, but between two times you go to the same page and open images from the same URI. Perhaps you have not subscribed to the event before the image was opened? Also the Source values used in the test page are external urls.

Comment: Hey Filip, what do you mean about the ImageOpened event? I do get that, but too often for the same image when using the FlipView control. Example when I have 20 images, the control will trigger 15 downloads and I get 15 ImageOpenend events. But when I go through the collection by flipping, the event will be triggered more than the total 20. Now the FadeInOnLoaded looks good, but I still need to show some 'download progress notification' and with the event counts not adding up correctly I'm still stuck :(

Comment: Hey Jennifer, so the DownloadProgress event is also not good enough, because with the flipview control I'm also getting multiple event hits for the same images.

Comment: Make sure you are not subscribing to the same event twice. If unsure - unsubscribe first before you subscribe to make sure your event handler is only trigerred once per event.

Comment: Hey Filip, how can I ensure that? The xaml of the flipview control needs a datatemplate to be defined, so in that datatemplate I only define one image control with the eventhandler also set in xaml. So I don't instantiate the 'pages' of the flipview myself and I don't subscribe in code behind.

Comment: Jennifer, I did a quick and dirty hack using the downloadprogress event. I add the image name in a collection when it's not in there yet when the progress is < 100 and remove it from the collection when progress is 100. While there are images in the collection I show the animation. Now the event gets fired to often but when the images are cached the animation is so quick you won't notice it.